# My program keeps looping on the print statement for some reason?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

There is a website with a bunch of free coding books, so I am trying to create a script to download all these books and categorize them.  I am trying to get the program to first print all the book links but when I tell it to find all the html links it prints them but the print statement keeps looping and prints the same html links over and over.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

main_url = requests.get('https://allitbooks.net')
results = BeautifulSoup(main_url.content, 'html.parser')
for result in results.find_all('a', href=True):
    if "category" in result.get('href'):
        book_links = requests.get('https://allitbooks.net' + str(result.get('href')))
        book_results = BeautifulSoup(book_links.content, 'html.parser')
        for results in book_results.find_all('a', href=True):
            if "html" in results.get('href'):
                print(str(results.get('href')))
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt to debug the code and diagnose the problem? For example, by checking what the values are of certain variables at various points in the loop?

Comment: Yes I did.  Took it one like at a time and still couldn't figure out why it's looping.

Comment: Put some white space in your code it should then become clear. At what point do you consider whether 'html' is in an href? Did you check the names of your variables at each point? (Not just the values)

Comment: It's printing the same URLs because all the category pages have lots of the same links.

Comment: Barmar, that would explain the code looping... I'll fix this tomorrow.  Thank you.